# Arduino LED Matrix algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, matrix, arduino

I need a method that will be able to output the following sequence

1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4,5 etc up to 9

The purpose of this is to create a sweeping horizontal effect on a 9x9 Led matrix using 2 arduinos, 1 controlling rows, 1 columns (I didn't have enough ports to be able to control from one Arduino uno, if you guys can offer suggestions on this other than an Arduino Mega then feel free to comment that too)

The arduinos communicate using parallel transmission e.g 0100 from Ard1 to Ard2 to signify column 4.

Comment: Do you have problems creating the sequence or output it to the device?

Comment: the sequence, outputing to the device works fine.

Comment: Isn't this a really simple sequence? You could generate it with two for loops, for example

Comment: I have a set function that translates column into binary before sending to second Ard e.g Set(1,9); signifies row 1, column 9

Comment: (The old school solution to _more low-speed digital outputs_ would include a serial-in-parallel-out shift register, preferably with "shadow register" such as the venerable 74HC 595.) With the bit pattern, think _shift register_ (initialise to all zeroes (or ones), shift cyclically with inversion) again - if it was the only one, ditch the MC.

Comment: immibis that's what I'm hoping, I'm fairly new to the programming game so  if you could show me that'd be great

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/RowColumnScanning

Comment: circuit and sketch image of your effect would be a good to share ... so we now what you mean by `1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4,5 etc up to 9`  .. how is your matrix connected? (hope some kind of parallel connection -> 18 pins to control) as suggested by @graybeard with single shift register you need just 10 pins to control which is usually available by most small MCU's btw which one MCU you use? ARDUINO is programming environment not the chip type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i= 1; i <10; ++i) {
    for (int j= 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        output(j);
    }
    // This is the break between sequences.
    sequence_clear();
}
```